# Drupal site webpages getting 500 in google

Tags: drupal, web-crawler

I am working on a site that is having issues when google tries to crawl over it. (I just inherited this site.) Google is returning a 500 error that it can not find the page. I have done some debug but I am stumped on what more to do.

Here is what I know:

- When google crawls the site it gets a 500 from some pages.  All the pages with the error seem to be *"~/content/~"* pages.
- When I try to manual fetch the page I also get the 500 error message.
- The issue only happens sometimes.
- Viewing the webpage in a browser gives no indication that anything is wrong.
- This is the error message from my error log.

> [17-Jul-2013 21:29:58] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in 
>   /home/~/public_html/sites/all/modules/ctools/plugins/access/php.inc(55) : eval()'d code on line 1

Sometime it says line 1 or line 2.

If I comment out the line below, the error goes away. I don't know what the function below does and if getting rid of it does any harm.

> // Provide a summary description based upon the checked roles.
>   function ctools_php_ctools_access_summary($conf, $contexts)
>   {
>     return !empty($conf['description']) ? check_plain($conf['description']) : t('No description');
>   }
>
> I spoke with the hosting company and they said everything is *"OK"* on their end.
>
> I submitted a question to the google forums and all the tools that they had me run against the site seemed to return successful information.
>
> The problem seems like its getting progressively worse over time.
>
> The apache log does not have any error messages in it.
>
> From the durpal Admin panel - Node template. When I select contexts for the column variant sometimes I get the WSOD.
>
> I don't see any php code anywhere that could be causing an error.
>
> Does anyone have any ideas what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end.... *if it's the case*

means that PHP has finished analyzing your code, but you forgot to close a symbol somewhere **in your page** or **in** *those that are* **included.**

Check:

- you may forgot to close a quote, so PHP continues to analyze your code until it finds the closing quotation-mark.
- You may forgot to close a bracket, so from the last opening, PHP thinks all the code that follows as part of a block that never ends.
- You may forgot to close a parenthesis, so from the last open parenthesis, it thinks all the code that follows as part of it and that is not ending.
- You may forgot a comma

Comment: Thank you for the comment back. Is there anyway to trace the php code to find out which files are included in call to display a webpage?  I have done this in other languages but I am new to drupal and php.

Comment: You can try EasyPHP with its extension xdebug trace.